# ctcdecode install fail - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-7zcjual1/

Tags: python, installation, pip, ctc

I try to install ctcdecode on ubuntu 18.04, but it is not easy.
First, I clone the repository to my server and error occurs when I 'pip install .' at the cloned root repository.
It is the guideline for installation.
git clone --recursive https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode.git
cd ctcdecode && pip install .

Here is my error message

```
Processing /home/skgudwn34/ctcdecode
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-7zcjual1/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        'third_party/boost_1_67_0.tar.gz')
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-7zcjual1/setup.py", line 22, in download_extract
        tar.extractall('third_party/')
      File "/home/skgudwn34/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 2000, in extractall
        numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
      File "/home/skgudwn34/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 2042, in extract
        numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
      File "/home/skgudwn34/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 2112, in _extract_member
        self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)
      File "/home/skgudwn34/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 2161, in makefile
        copyfileobj(source, target, tarinfo.size, ReadError, bufsize)
      File "/home/skgudwn34/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 247, in copyfileobj
        buf = src.read(bufsize)
      File "/home/skgudwn34/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 287, in read
        return self._buffer.read(size)
      File "/home/skgudwn34/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
        data = self.read(len(byte_view))
      File "/home/skgudwn34/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 493, in read
        raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
    EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-7zcjual1/
```

I search solution for days.
Many people recommend upgrading setuptools, but it didn't work.
How can I do to resolve my problem.
Please help. I look forward to your comment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because of an incomplete download of the `boost_1_67_0.tar.gz` file, as is indicated by the error message: `EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached`.

I would recommend downloading the boost file from [here](https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/boost_1_67_0.tar.gz) and replacing the `ctcdecode/third_party/boost_1_67_0.tar.gz` file with the complete, downloaded one. Let me know if that works!

Edit: Might be worth it to download the `openfst` tar as well [from here](https://www.openslr.org/resources/2/openfst-1.6.7.tar.gz) and replacing the one in `third_party/` as well.